# Dynamically appearing suffixIcon in TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My aim is to build a search box using TextField which have a icon button in the end of the field to clear out what is in the text field. Currently I'm using,

```
TextField(
   controller: _searchFieldController,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     filled: true,
     fillColor: Colors.white,
     prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
     border: OutlineInputBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
     hintText: 'Search here...',
     hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
     suffixIcon: _searchFieldController.text.length > 0 ? IconButton(
       onPressed: () {
          _searchFieldController.clear();
       },
       icon: Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.grey)
     ) : null,
  ),
),
```

with following text editing controller.

```
final _searchFieldController = TextEditingController();

_searchFieldController.addListener(() {
    print(_searchFieldController.text.length);
});
```

But the suffixIcon never appears. Can anyone tell how to get this right?

Answer (score 2):

Try having a state variable for length and inside add listener function set the length and check the length for the icon visibility

```
final _searchFieldController = TextEditingController();
final _length = 0;

_searchFieldController.addListener(() {
    setState(() => _length = _searchFieldController.text.length);
});
```

then check the _length variable

```
suffixIcon: _length > 0 ? IconButton(
   onPressed: () {
      _searchFieldController.clear();
   },
   icon: Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.grey)
 ) : null
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. After I put a setState inside the listener, entered characters do not appear inside the TextField. And the clear button also does not appear.

Comment: try having a state variable for text also

Answer (score 2):

ValueListenableBuilder can listen to textEditingControllers. So we can have an implementation like this:
Define `suffixIcon` inside your build method of the the widget.

```
 final suffixIcon = ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: controller,
  builder: (_, value, ___) {
    if (value.text.isNotEmpty) {
      return IconButton(
        onPressed: () => controller.clear(),
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.cancel,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return const SizedBox.shrink();
    }
  },
);
```

Use it inside the `TextField` decoration:

```
    TextField(
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        suffixIcon:suffixIcon,
        .....
```

Answer (score 0):

simply put the `setState((){})` in onChange like

```
  onChange: (value) {
    setState(() {});
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implementing suffixIcon property to solve your this error.

```
TextFormField(
          suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
          onChanged: (value) {},
          hintText: ConstString.firstName,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value!.isEmpty) {
              return ConstString.enterFirstName;
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          },
          controller: _firstName,
        ),
```